# How to filter components in in ul Angular

Tags: html, angular, filter

I have that piece of code and I want to filter the `<app-list-item>` component by the title of the post.
How can I implement that in my example?

```
<div
      id="postsDiv"
      style="
        height: 330px;
        width: 97.5%;
        display: none;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        background-color: red;
        overflow: scroll;
      "
    >
      <div id="search-box-div">
        <div id="search-field">
          <input #input type="text" placeholder="Filter" style="width: 100%" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4" *ngFor="let post of myPosts;" >
        <app-list-item [post]="post"></app-list-item>
      </ul>
    </div
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Component

```
@Component({
...
})
class ListWithSearchComponent {
  myPosts: Array<any>
  filteredPosts: Array<any>
  filterText = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    // initialize myPosts ...
    this.filteredPosts = this.myPosts;
  }

  onFilterTextChange() {
    this.filteredPosts = this.myPosts.filter(post => {
        return post.title.indexOf(this.filterText) > -1;
    })
  }
}
```

In your template

```
<div
      id="postsDiv"
      style="
        height: 330px;
        width: 97.5%;
        display: none;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        background-color: red;
        overflow: scroll;
      "
    >
      <div id="search-box-div">
        <div id="search-field">
          <input #input type="text" placeholder="Filter" style="width: 100%" [(ngModel)]="filterText" (ngModelChange)="onFilterTextChange()" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4" *ngFor="let post of filteredPosts;" >
        <app-list-item [post]="post"></app-list-item>
      </ul>
    </div
```